# How to install recent Node.js on Asustor (AS3304T)

Tags: node.js, installation, nas

I just purchased an Asustor AS3304T and the app central offers
to install a pretty old version of Node.js (10.13.0.r4.0.4)

I also have a few Raspberry pi devices and have been writing
some Node.js utilities using version 16.13.2.

Since I am not sure if I used features not supported by 10.x
I would prefer installing same or more recent version of Node.js,
possibly the lates LTS version: 16.18.9.

I use some Raspberry pies, but I am not a linux expert.
Just want to know if it can be done without causing problems
on the Asustor system.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a long time and the lonely solution i found is to install Entware from App Central.
I suggest to remove first the Nodejs app before installing the one provided by Entware.

Once done just
`opkg install node`
`opkg install node-npm`
and you will get node `v16.16.0` and npm `8.11.0`

Comment: It worked thanks!  It's been a while so now I get node v16.19.1 and npm 8.19.3.

Comment: I was also able to upgrade to npm 9.6.2 immediately after this.